# Resizing animated GIF using GraphicsMagick

Tags: c++, linux, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have an animated `gif` image with transparent frames.
I need to resize it.

Before resizing, I use the `Magick::coalesceImages` function, after I resize the image I use the `Magick::writeImages` function to collect all the `gif` frames back into one single image.

The problem is that the output resized image file size is bigger than the original one, because the original animated `gif` had transparent frames, and the new resized `gif` does not have any transparent frames.

I have read about frame optimization on [www.imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/#frame_opt) plus I can see on [www.graphicsmagick.org](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Image.html) the `gifDisposeMethod` function.

My question is, how can I cause the resized animated `gif` image to use transparency frames and avoid the increase on the image `KBytes` size?

Comment: thanks for fixing my gramer errors, but i could really use an answer...

Comment: You would expect it to be bigger if you resized the frames bigger -- what is the difference in pixel width/height and what is the difference in KB of the file?

Comment: well the original image is 230X40 10,896Bytes. after using the Magick::coalesceImage and resizing the image to 213X37 and i get 108,207bytes of image.
i can see that once i resize the image to 92%%92% of it's original size, without using the coalesceImage (since i am using precentages, each frame will be resize according to it's original dimensions, so i figured i can remove the coalesceImage usage) i get a much smaller image 15,226Bytes which is still bigger than the original image. and i cant really understand how come i got a bigger image

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found the way to go:

When resizing an animated `gif`, using `Magick::coalesceImages()` is not the best way...

Instead I am rezising according to percentage sizing and not absolute sizing, while skipping the `Magick::coalesceImages()` call.

For example, lets say my original animated `gif` is 300x300 and I want to resize it to be 150x150, I'll do the following:

- Read the image in a `Magick::Blob`
- Calculate the percentage numbers (50%x50% in my demo case)
- Resize each and every frame of the image according to the percentage calculations.

This way we are not increasing each frame size because we are not using the `Magick::coalesceImages()` function and we are resizing each frame according to its original size, so we don't have any problem with the transparency of the frame.